# Difference between Java JDK release Version

Tags: java, java-deployment-toolkit

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

This link contain java development toolkit.

**Question is:**
Difference between Java JDK 8u91 AND JDK 8u92 ?

Which version would you recommend?

Comment: Look at the updates and changelogs....

Comment: Which version you recommend to me?

Comment: Choose for yourself. Just search up the version and look at what was changed. Probably pretty minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) that preceded the page you linked says it:

> Java SE 8u91 includes important security fixes. Oracle strongly recommends that all Java SE 8 users upgrade to this release. Java SE 8u92 is a patch-set update, including all of 8u91 **plus additional features (described in the release notes)**.
>   [Learn more](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/8u-relnotes-2225394.html)   [image: arrow]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have specific requirements (and you almost never will), always go for the newest. The differences between minor Java versions are only bug fixes & security patches.